# iPhone not forgetting test user account (in app purchase)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

While adding in some in-app-purchases to an app, I created a test user account in iTunes Connect.  After "buying" the items in the store with the test user, I then deleted that test user and created another.

The problem I'm having is that the phone still asks for the original test account's password constantly.  This test account isn't logged in under the "iTunes & App Store" settings, nor anywhere else I'm aware of.

I've tried doing a backup & restore, and still no progress.  Does this issue sound familiar?  Any ideas of other things to try would be terrific.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: So there is no test user account set up in your device's settings and still when you do in app purchase from your app, it directly ask you the password for your previous test user account?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming, but usage of Apple's App Store.

Comment: @Manthan:  Yup, that's exactly it.  And this test account has since been deleted from iTunes Connect as well.

Comment: whether the test account exists or not but if you don't have any accounts set up in your device then, it will open a pop up with another options "Create new apple id", "Use existing id" and other. Please make sure again from your settings if its there or not.

Comment: @OwenHartnett Using the app under development yields prompt after prompt for the user to login to a "ghost" account.  It's fair to assume that the cause of this issue is somewhere in the programming.  For example, perhaps the code to "flush out" interrupted transactions isn't correct, and so the program can't get past that state.

Comment: I just did it in my app and it is working perfectly well. If not then restart your device.

Comment: @Manthan Thanks for the reply.  Yes, my normal Apple ID is currently setup on the device.

Comment: So please delete that account from your device man. You will be good to go then.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem was specific to iOS 8 Beta 4.  It's gone away on a different testing device that's running iOS 7.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have signed out test user account from within your device:

1. Sign out of the app store from Settings in iOS: Go to Settings >
   iTunes & App Store, tap your Apple ID, then tap ‘Sign Out’
2. In your app, initiate your IAP
3. You will be prompted to enter credentials for username and password

Hope this helps!